# Python Selenium: How do you Edit the YouTube Channel Dropdown?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, youtube

I am using Selenium with Python to do some webscraping on Youtube. After going to a particular Youtube channel, I would like to switch the "Sort By" dropdown menu from "Date added (newest)" to "Date added (oldest)" (aka from the newest videos on top to the oldest videos on top), but I am having trouble locating the dropdown menu in Selenium. Does anyone know how to call on the dropdown and edit it?

Code thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/familyfeud/videos')
# Insert code to find and edit the "Sort By" dropdown here
```

(I chose the Family Feud channel randomly as an example.)

Comment: How would I change it to accept answers? Maybe I have it on the wrong setting. I want answers (otherwise, I wouldn't be asking).

Comment: I am not aware of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/familyfeud/videos')

WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="sort-menu"]/yt-sort-filter-sub-menu-renderer/yt-dropdown-menu'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="menu"]/a[2]/tp-yt-paper-item'))).click()
```

Please do accept this answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the link rather than automating the behavior.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
url = "https://www.youtube.com/c/familyfeud/videos"
sorted_by_oldest = url + "?sort=da"
driver.get(sorted_by_oldest)
```

`sort=da` sorts by the oldest. 
`sort=dd` sorts by the newest.